# Simple radar 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question. For a simple game, I need an improvised, simple radar. everything I've done up to now is just what you see in the picture. only that line is rotated.

[image: radar]

Now I want to make that blue dot appear random somewhere in the circle, and when the radar comes to him to appear.

```
using EduUtils.Events;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

public class RadarScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject radarLine;
   private Vector3 rotationEuler;

   void Start ()
   {

   }
   private void Update()
   {
       rotationEuler -= Vector3.forward * 50 * Time.deltaTime;
       radarLine.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationEuler);
   }

}
```

This script only makes the rotation but I'm trying to think how to make that point appear in front of the radar during the rotation.???

Comment: You know where the blue dot is, you know where the radar line is - so exactly what is the problem with deciding if the blue dot is displayed or not?

Comment: initially it is inactive, and only when it enters the radar beam is observed, and every time it changes its position

Comment: ???? Where is you difficulty in knowing if it has entered the radar beam - even if it is moving you know where it is & where the radar beam is - I assume you are controlling both.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable renderer when the dots enter radar sector:

```
public class RadarScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject radarLine;
    private Vector3 rotationEuler;

    private void Update()
    {
        rotationEuler -= Vector3.forward * 50 * Time.deltaTime;
        radarLine.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationEuler);
        var sectorA = radarLine.transform.up;
        var sectorB = -radarLine.transform.right;
        var allDots = GetComponentsInChildren<RadarDot> ();
        foreach (var dot in allDots) {
            var a = Vector3.Dot (dot.transform.position, sectorA);
            var b = Vector3.Dot (dot.transform.position, sectorB);
            dot.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = (a > 0 && b < 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to use dot product sign to check if the dot lies between two sector vectors. RadarDot in the example is just a sprite in random position:

```
public class RadarDot : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var randomPos = Random.insideUnitCircle;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (randomPos.x, randomPos.y);
        GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;

    }
}
```